# App size become double after migrating to androidX

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app whose previous size was 51 mb. I needed to upgrade the compiled sdk version to 29 because of which I migrated my app to androidx layouts. But now when I am making release of the app its size has been double 107 mb. I am very confused what should I do. I analyzed the apk and the most of the app size is because of the lib folder. I checked the previous version apk and in that lib folder is of 51 mb.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.i2vsys.i2vApp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 11
        versionName "7"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true

        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')

    implementation 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
    implementation 'com.github.johnkil.print:print:1.2.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:0.2.15'
    //  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4' // Apache commons for i/o

    implementation 'io.github.memfis19:annca:0.3.5'
    implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.2.3'
    compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/uploadservice-3.0-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.5'
    implementation 'de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

[image: Apk inspection]
[image: apk comparision]

I have also observed that apk size once reached to 150 mb then I cleaned the solution and apk size reduced and when I install it by usb while developing its size is only 35 mb.

Comment: Well, which libraries do you have in those `lib` subdirectories? Do you need all of them?

Comment: No. How can I remove those?